# How to find specific regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a data analyzing script and therefore I'm checking the cells of an excel sheet for occuring error codes. For each error code I iterate through my error code list and check for every single code if there is a regex match in that cell.

Some codes have 4 digits and some have 6.

The problem is now, for all the 6 digit codes that somewhere in itself have the same sequence as one of the 4 digits codes, there is a regex match for this 4 digit code and it will be counted even if this 4 digit code doesn't occure in this cell.

Here is a small code example which makes the problem quite clear I think.

```
errorcodes = [1234, 123456]
cell = "This is the cell containing the error 123456"
counter = 0

for i in range(2):
    if re.search(str(errorcodes[i]), cell):
        counter += 1

if counter == 2:
    print("This is the wrong number of errors")
elif counter == 1:
    print("This is the right number of errors")
```

Comment: You should learn more about RegEx metacharacters it can be help to specific the pattern

Answer (score 0):

The regex search method is being asked to look for `1234` in the string `123456`, so it does find a match. But of course it also finds a match when you look for `123456`. What you want is to find only the match on the whole of the error code.

You can do this by searching the string between word boundaries. A word boundary is signified by the regex metacharacter `\b`, which you can use like this:

```
re.search(rf"\b{errorcodes[i]}\b", cell)
```

As part of a revised version of your code:

```
import re

errorcodes = [1234, 123456]
cell = "This is the cell containing the error 123456"
counter = 0

for i in range(2):
    if re.search(rf"\b{errorcodes[i]}\b", cell):
        counter += 1

if counter == 2:
    print("This is the wrong number of errors")
elif counter == 1:
    print("This is the right number of errors")
```

I decided to use Python 3.6's f-formatted strings to make it easier to specify the search regex.